Property 'accountName' does not exist on type 'AccountNamespace<ProgramName>'.ts(2339)
Trying to fetch data from an on-chain account using Anchor and getting the error Property 'accountName' does not exist on type 'AccountNamespace<ProgramName>'.ts(2339)
fetch method
const accountState = await program.account.derivedAccount.fetch(derivedAccountAddress);

environment
solana-cli 1.18.8
anchor-cli 0.29.0
